# Converting Makefile to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake, ros

I'm using a developement board that has its own libraries. I have installed ROS on it and now I need to use publish/subscribe by including its libraries to the CMakeLists.txt of the package. I have to also note that I use Eclipse for compilation, so the CMakeLists.txt is in that form. Here is the Makefile of hardware library that I want to use in CMakeLists.txt:

```
DIR=$(shell pwd)/../

INCS = -I.\
        -I$(DIR) \
        -I$(DIR)/hardware \
        -I$(DIR)/hardware/environment \
        -I$(DIR)/hardware/environment/cores \
        -I$(DIR)/hardware/environment/cores/environment \
        -I$(DIR)/hardware/environment/variants \
        -I$(DIR)/hardware/environment/variants/sunxi \
        -I$(DIR)/libraries \
        -I$(DIR)/libraries/Serial \
        -I$(DIR)/libraries/SPI \
    -I$(DIR)/libraries/Wire \
    -I$(DIR)/libraries/LiquidCrystal \
    -I$(DIR)/Basibos/include LIBS=../libenvironment.a TARGET=../output/test

OBJS = BasibosAnaProgram

all: 
    @mkdir -p $(TARGET)
    for i in $(OBJS); do echo "$(CXX) $(INCS) $$i.cpp -o $(TARGET)/$$i $(LIBS)"; done
    @for i in $(OBJS); do $(CXX) $(INCS) $$i.cpp -o $(TARGET)/$$i $(LIBS); done

clean:
    @for i in $(OBJS); do rm -f $(TARGET)/$$i; done
```

And here is the example CMakeLists.txt that Makefile should be included:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Basibos.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/HedefeGitme.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Konum.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Robot.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Sonar.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Zaman.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/XMLAyiklayici.cpp)

rosbuild_add_executable(srctest RobotKontrol.cpp)

target_link_libraries(srctest ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

I'm stuck and can't go forward without help. Any help will be greately appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists

You have to add the source files in following fashion:

```
rosbuild_add_library(XmlRpc src/XmlRpcClient.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcDispatch.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcServer.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcServerConnection.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcServerMethod.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcSocket.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcSource.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcUtil.cpp
                   src/XmlRpcValue.cpp)
```